# C# graph line control

Tags: c#, graph, controls, line

Hello I am searching for a graph control that will allow me to make Line Graphs like this:[Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDVnt.jpg)

And to be able to add new points every sec for example and the graph to move to the left and so on.

Basicly I need time based graph line control.

Does someone can help me?

I want to make the program on normal C# win form application

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Web?  What have you looked at so far?

Comment: we cant help you unless you tell use what platform you are coding for--win forms, ASP.net, silverlight, wpf, etc.

Comment: C# .NET4 win form application

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WinForm Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837087/c-sharp-winform-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a complete tutorial on the built-in chart-control in visual studio 2010 [here](http://f5debug.net/2011/05/04/chart-control-in-visual-studio-2010-web-and-windows-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

This will help you hopefully.  [C# Graphs](http://www.gigasoft.com/netgraph.html)